# How find this limit $\lim_{p\to 0^{+}}\left(\int_{a}^{m-p}f(x)dx+\int_{m+p}^{b}f(x)dx\right)$

Tags: integration, limits

> Give real numbers $a,b$ such that $0<a<b$ and $m=\dfrac{a+b}{2}<\dfrac{\pi}{4}$,Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{p\to 0^{+}}\left(\int_{a}^{m-p}f(x)dx+\int_{m+p}^{b}f(x)dx\right)$$
>   where
>   $$f(x)=\dfrac{(1+\cos{(2m-2x)})\cos{(a-x)}\cos{(b-x)}}{(1-\sin{(a-x)})(1-\sin{(b-x)})\sin{(2m-2x)}}$$

Now I think follow idea is usefull

**Idea**:

since
$$\dfrac{1+\cos{(2m-2x)}}{\sin{(2m-2x)}}=\tan{(m-x)}$$
and
$$\dfrac{\cos{(a-x)}}{1-\sin{(a-x)}}=\tan{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{a-x}{2}\right)}$$
$$\dfrac{\cos{(b-x)}}{1-\sin{(b-x)}}=\tan{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{b-x}{2}\right)}$$.
so
$$f(x)=\tan{(m-x)}\cdot \tan{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{a-x}{2}\right)}\cdot \tan{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{b-x}{2}\right)}$$
since
$$m=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$$
so also have
$$\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{a-x}{2}\right)+\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{b-x}{2}\right)
=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\dfrac{a+b}{2}-x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+(m-x)$$

then I fell I will silve it,But can't it deal this integral.

and this problem is interesting

This problem is from The College Mathematics Joutnoal Vol.44.No.3 May 2013 problem,and I can't have this journal.

can see [joutnoal](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.4169/college.math.j.44.3.233?uid=2134&uid=3739984&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104591666281)

Comment: This is an interesting problem! It certainly seems as though trig identities will come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first identity is wrong:
$$\frac{1+\cos(2m-2x)}{\sin(2m-2x)}=\tan\left(x-m+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
So your function simplifies to:
$$ f(x)=\tan\left(x-m+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{a-x}{2}\right)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{b-x}{2}\right)$$

You can use the triple tangent identity: if $x+y+z=\pi$, then $\tan(x)+\tan(y)+\tan(z)=\tan(x)\tan(y)\tan(z)$.
So:
$$ f(x)=\tan\left(x-m+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{a-x}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{b-x}{2}\right)$$
Now the three terms can be integrated separately.

Edit: the further calculation is not complicated conceptually, but still an annoying task. If I did not make mistakes, the result simplifies to:

$$\log\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)}\right|
+
2\log\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{b-a}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}\right|$$
which further simplifies to
$$
2\tan\left(\frac{a-b}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

I did not thoroughly check this, so it is probable that somewhere I forgot a minus sign or was not careful with taking absolute values.